# Creating and Calling Stored Procedures using MySQL and C# ASPNET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures, odbc

I want creating stored procedures in MySql using the `OdbcCommand` class.

After the stored procedure is named, I define one `OdbcCommand` parameter for every parameter in the stored procedure.

`IN parameters` are defined with the parameter name and the object containing the value, `OUT parameters` are defined with the parameter name and the data type that is expected to be returned.

All parameters need the parameter direction defined.

The following C# code it's my test.

The SP it's created correctly but I have error on

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community] You
> have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that corresponds
> to your MySQL server version  for the right syntax to use near
> 'add_emp' at line 1

On this part of C# code

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "add_emp;";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", "Jones");
    cmd.Parameters["@tname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@empno", OdbcType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@empno"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  <<< Line of error

    Response.Write("Employee exists: " + cmd.Parameters["@empno"].Value);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Any suggestion?

```
using (OdbcConnection conn =
   new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
{
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandText = "DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_emp";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE PROCEDURE add_emp(" +
                          "IN tname VARCHAR(255), OUT empno INT)" +
                          "BEGIN SELECT EXISTS( SELECT empo FROM do_table WHERE name = tname ) INTO @titem_id; " +
                          "SET empno = @titem_id; END";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    conn.Close();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandText = "add_emp;";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tname", "Jones");
        cmd.Parameters["@tname"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empno", OdbcType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@empno"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Write("Employee exists: " + cmd.Parameters["@empno"].Value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: your procedure makes no sense, what do you try  to achieve?

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;` instead, which will preserve your stack trace. Or better yet, ditch the try/catch here altogether, as it's not doing anything of value. If the only thing you're doing in a catch block is rethrowing, then the catch block isn't needed.

Comment: The procedure code is correct itself (if there is no invisible symbols in it). The error is ODBC driver error, the query didn't even get to MySQL server. And your connector version is too old - maybe it's a time to upgrade it?

Comment: @Akina Thanks Akina, I have upgraded the ODBC driver. Now work!